# delete trigger in quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to delete a scheduled trigger with a specific job? It seems that only way to delete a trigger is to delete the whole job and then re-register the job and trigger.

I've a job which can potentially have 100+ triggers and I really don't want to delete the job and re-register all the triggers when I just have to delete 1 trigger.

Also, is there a way to stop the scheduler from executing the job as soon as the trigger is configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

try `scheduler.unscheduleJob`

this accepts the trigger and group names as a parameters and will only remove the trigger specified, not the job.

[QuartzScheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#unscheduleJob%28org.quartz.core.SchedulingContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

[Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#unscheduleJob%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

[Forum](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/forums/show/17.page)

Comment: I tried doing getTriggersOfJob before and after doing unscheduleJob. It doesn't remove the trigger. Once I remove do I need to do something else to make the scheduler aware?

Comment: The answers in the link are gone

Comment: Just in case someone runs into the same issue that I had - The job WILL be removed unless you call the storeDurably() method when building it. i.e JobBuilder jobBuilder = new JobBuilder(), jobBuilder.storeDurably()

Comment: The job will not be removed if the job has any other triggers even if it is not configured durable. (at least for 2.3.2)