# Why Spring Quart Scheduler Job running more intervals than expected

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am working on a job thats needs to run every 6 hours,
I have used this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule)

My job is being executed every couple of minutes while i dont expect it to run this often, i have set the trigger to run every 6 hours with

```
.withSchedule(simpleSchedule().repeatForever().withIntervalInHours(SIX_HOURS))
```

So why Spring Quart Scheduler Job running more times than the intervals as expected.

And created tables for spring quartz as described [here](https://github.com/StackAbuse/spring-boot-quartz/blob/master/src/main/resources/db/quartz_tables_h2.sql)

And this is my Code

**quartz maven version:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**quart.properties**

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DirectDataLoader
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
```

**The Job class**

```
@Component
public class AbortStuckExecutionLogsJob implements Job {
private final HistoryLogService historyLogService;

@Autowired
public AbortStuckExecutionLogsJob(HistoryLogService historyLogService) {
    this.historyLogService = historyLogService;
}

@Override
@TimberLogTask(name = ABORT_ZOMBIE_EXECUTION_LOGS)
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    historyLogService.abortStuckExecutionLogs();
}
```

}

**SpringQuartzScheduler class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringQuartzScheduler {

    public static final int SIX_HOURS = 6;
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringQuartzScheduler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public Trigger trigger(JobDetail job) {
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(job)
                .withIdentity("abort_stuck_jobs")
                .withDescription("abort zombies executions trigger")
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().repeatForever().withIntervalInHours(SIX_HOURS))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetail jobDetail() {
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob().ofType(AbortStuckExecutionLogsJob.class)
                .storeDurably()
                .withIdentity("abort_stuck_jobs")
                .build();
        return jobDetail;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler(Trigger trigger, JobDetail job, DataSource quartzDataSource) {
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"));
        schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
        schedulerFactory.setJobDetails(job);
        schedulerFactory.setTriggers(trigger);
        schedulerFactory.setDataSource(quartzDataSource);
        return schedulerFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
        SpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new SpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to test it with Integration Test or manual testing with console?

Comment: With my IDE - and having a break point on inside AbortStuckExecutionLogsJob::execute

Comment: Can you check REPEATE_INTERVAL column in database table QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS if it is set wrong maybe there is some bug.

Comment: You can use org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX to persist or retrieve it from/to database

Comment: Good catch i have - 2 rows there, is there a way of removing Triggers after each deployment ?

Comment: You can delete it with trigger name and trigger_group by using JDBCTemplate but there can be some api calls let me check.

Comment: scheduler.unscheduleJob api call can remove it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904064/delete-trigger-in-quartz